# Node.JS Token Replacement (equivalent of calling inline function in ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Right now, I have an ASP.NET application where, within the aspx files, at various points, I call a function which inserts standard template HTML.  For example:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<%=SectionHeader('Section title 1') %>
some content for section 1
<%=SectionHeader('Section title 2') %>
some content for section 2
</body>
</html>
```

So wherever the SectionHeader function was called, it would read the passed in parameter, and insert the HTML for the section header, such as {title}.  I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish the same thing in Node.

I understand how to do a basic token replacement - reading a static HTML file, looking for a token (such as {token1}) and replacing it with something.  But short of using Regex and complex string manipulation, is there any way to accomplish the same thing in Node that I'm doing with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the generated application skeleton, and modified the `index.js` and `index.jade` to pass a function into the template.  I think is what you are asking for, but there may be opinions if this is a good architecture to have the template call back into logic.

index.js

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  var fn = function(initial) {
      return initial + ". Tester";
  };
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express', fn : fn });
};
```

index.jade

```
block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}

  div Hello #{fn('A')}
```

Now, when I load `http://localhost:3000/`, this is what renders on the screen.  Notice the "A" is being passed into the function to generate the string "A. Tester" for the output.

---

**Express**

Welcome to Express

Hello A. Tester

Answer (score 0):

There are [lots of templating engines](http://nodetoolbox.com/categories/Templating) for node, maybe you should try one of these. If you are searching for a web application framework [express](http://expressjs.com/) would be a good starting point, which has support for many templating enignes.

Of course you could do just string replacement, but a templating engine provides much more.

Comment: I have been using Express a lot (since getting started a month ago) and I'm still exploring it.  I read everything I could find about EJS and Jade, and I can't find any documentation for either of them that would explain how I can accomplish this.  From the way I understand it, the way they do templating is through tokens - so you can say {title} and it will replace all instances of {title} with something you specify.  I can't for the life of me find how you can pass IN a value of some sort TO the templating engine to use as part of it's templating mechanism.

Comment: In Jade you have to possibilities: Either use a mixin to have a "subtemplate" or extend another jade file (normally a layout) to render your block in a layout. Your example would resemble a layout file. You can have a tepmlate that defines various blocks that can fill in placeholders in your layout. https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#template-inheritance

Comment: thanks!  mixin was exactly what i was looking for!  any chance you know if that same concept is available in other templating engines?  im just not that used to using jade yet